# como faço para mostrar esse elemento ao contrario so que em um alert so?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Mostrador JavaScript ao normal</h1>
    <script>
        let vetor = [" Script ","Java"];
        let i = 0;
        var resultado = 0;
         function Mostrar(){
            for(i=vetor.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                alert(vetor[i]+" ");
            }

         }


    </script>
    <button onclick="Mostrar()">Mostrar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consegue epecificar melhor?

Comment: Tipo preciso mostrar o elemento do vetor   em um alert só, esta "Script", "Java"... quero mostrar com um alert so "Java Script", sem utilização, da função reverse().

Answer (score 0):

Olá adicione um **alert(seuvetor.reverse());**  O método `**reverse ()**`  é usado para reversão do array. O primeiro elemento da matriz se torna o último elemento e vice-versa.

exemplo:

```
<script>
let lista = ["Script","Java"];
function teste(){
    alert(lista.reverse());

}
</script>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

        <button onclick="teste()" >Mostrar</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Já várias formas de fazer isso. Abaixo explico duas delas.

#### Concatenação

Para mesclar vários textos numa só variável, basta utilizar a concatenação (juntar) os textos. No JavaScript você pode utilizar a função [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) ou o operador <kbd>[+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators)</kbd>.

```js
let vetor = [" Script ", "Java"];
let i = 0;

function Mostrar() {
  let result = "";

  for (i = vetor.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result += vetor[i] + " "
  }
  
  alert(result)
}
```

```html
<h1>Mostrador JavaScript ao normal</h1>
<button onclick="Mostrar()">Mostrar</button>
```

#### Arrays

Como você está trabalhando com *arrays*, por você utilizar os métodos [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) e/ou [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
let vetor = [" Script ", "Java"];

function MostrarSimples() {
  /**
   * Clona o array. Isso evita que no segundo clique,
   * por exemplo, apareça "Script java"
   */
  let newArr = [...vetor]
  
  let result = newArr.reverse() // Troca a ordem dos valores (o primeiro torna-se o último etc)
    .join("") // Junta os valores. Isso evita que apareça, por exemplo "Java, Script"
  
  alert(result)
}

function MostrarComplexo() {
  /**
   * Clona o array. Isso evita que no segundo clique,
   * por exemplo, apareça "Script java"
   */
  let newArr = [...vetor]
  
  let result = newArr.reverse() // Troca a ordem dos valores (o primeiro torna-se o último etc)
    .map(value => value.trim()) // Remove os espaços em branco. Evita " Java  Script"
    .join(" ") // Junta os valores separando-os com um espaço
    
  alert(result)
}
```

```html
<h1>Mostrador JavaScript ao normal</h1>
<button onclick="MostrarSimples()">Mostrar 1</button>
<button onclick="MostrarComplexo()">Mostrar 2</button>
```